# Gnosis API is responding incorrectly which has stopped our onboarding (at Parcel)

Tags: dao, gnosis

gm

GET
​/owners​/{address}​/safes​/
Return Safes where the address provided is an owner

This API is responding with empty array for all the addresses. It has halted our onboarding for DAOs. Can we fix this at the earliest? Our support depends on yours :)

Thanks,
Anubhav, Parcel
https://parcel.money

Comment: This looks more like a bug report than a question. You should [report it to the Gnosis team](https://github.com/gnosis/safe-transaction-service/issues/new/choose) instead.

Answer (score 0):

This endpoint is currently not available due to server maintenance.

This is potentially not a question that should be asked in this forum and therefore I would recommend to close it.

Feel free to open bug reports on the transaction repository or reach out to the team on their [discord](https://chat.gnosis-safe.io)